# how to change devise's flash[:notice] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

I'm using rails 2.3.5 and devise 1.0.6.
I'm having users confirm account's with email.
However, when a new user sign's up the flash notice says "The user was successfully created" which it was but it doesn't tell the user that they need to confirm their their email unless they try to log in and devise's flash notice still doesn't explain that they have to confirm through email.

Where is this flash notice located in the gem and how can I change it? Or what is a better way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just enable i18n in your project and edit the default locale (en.devise.yml) or download new ones from 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/i18n

Comment: Thanks, I see. So more applicable to what I asked just change the .en local file - if you add this to your answer I'll give you a check otherwise I will add the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Flash messages for the devise gem can be altered in the locales directory (YourRailsApp/config/locales/devise.en.yml).

Just change the `devise.en.yml` to your liking, it doesn't really take any programming knowledge.

If you are new to rails the locales directory is for I18n translations which is rails way of translating words albeit statically but it works well for simple projects.